# Run a total of N jobs, having M of them running in parallel at any time

Tags: python, bash, shell, parallel-processing

I have a lots of jobs to run, let's say 100. They can run in parallel, but each of them takes up a lot of memory, so I can only run 8 at the same time.

I currently have this shell script:

```
(
(python run.py $arg1 &)
(python run.py $arg2 &)
(python run.py $arg3 &)
(python run.py $arg4 &)
(python run.py $arg5 &)
(python run.py $arg6 &)
(python run.py $arg7 &)
(python run.py $arg8 &)
) 2>&1 | cat -u

(
(python run.py $arg9 &)
(python run.py $arg10 &)
(python run.py $arg11 &)
(python run.py $arg12 &)
(python run.py $arg13 &)
(python run.py $arg14 &)
(python run.py $arg15 &)
(python run.py $arg16 &)
) 2>&1 | cat -u

...
```

This has the effect of running the first batch of eight, and when they are all finished, it starts the next batch of 8. The problem is that the running time is not constant for each job, and some finish before others, so it is not optimal to weight for each batch of 8 to be finished, as I am effectively waiting for the slowest amongst the 8 to be done.

Instead, I would like to have a script (shell or python) that will run all my 100 jobs, with having 8 of them in parallel at any given time, for optimal efficiency.

Any idea about of to achieve that?

Comment: What is `cat -u` supposed to do? According to the [manpage](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cat) -u is ignored.

Comment: @NickODell TBH I copied this script from somewhere, so I am not sure. My man displays something different though: "-u Disable output buffering."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write your own little scheduler, hiving them off to processors that are done with their current assignment; but at our centre [we strongly recommend](https://support.scinet.utoronto.ca/wiki/index.php/User_Serial) using [gnu parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/), which has already implemented that with an xargs-like syntax.

So for instance, as above, you could do

```
parallel --max-procs 8 <<EOF
  python run.py $arg1 
  python run.py $arg2 
  python run.py $arg3
  ..
EOF
```

Or, if you had your argument list in a file, you could do something like

```
cat args.list | parallel --max-procs 8 python run.py
```

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your needs, you can use many tools. The simplest will probably be using [`GNU parallel`](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). `make` can run tasks in parallel with its `-j` switch. If the tasks you try to run are more complex and diverse, a real queueing system might help, e.g. [Dr. Queue](https://ssl.drqueue.org/redmine/projects/drqueue/wiki/Documentation). There are many more tools, [GNU parallel's man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#differences_between_gnu_parallel_and_alternatives) lists them nicely.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you're looking for the [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module, specifically [`multiprocessing.Pool`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool).

If I were doing this, I would give all the different sets of arguments to run.py, wrap what you do at the toplevel right now in run.py in a `main(args)` function, and then use Pool's map method to call that method over all the different sets of arguments.

It might look something like this:

```
import multiprocessing

def main(args):
  # Here's where you would do what you usually do with the arguments

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8)
pool.map(main, sys.argv[1:], chunksize=1)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Note that this assumes the arguments for each run can be held in one string (and thus one entry of `sys.argv`).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use DataStage's own Workload Management?  Define M queues and allocate your N jobs round robin onto those queues.